# Inner page state cant resolve service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing very strange issue, while home page can resolve service data, the exactly the same thing is failed for inner page, here is my route code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'app/layout/home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
            pressData: function (HomeService) {
                return HomeService.pressService().query().$promise;
            },
            countryData: function (countryservice) {
                return countryservice.countryServiceData().query().$promise;
            }
        }
    })
    .state('create', {
        url: '/event/create',
        templateUrl: 'app/layout/create-event/create-event.html',
        controller: 'CreateEventController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {
            countryData: function (countryservice) {
                return countryservice.countryServiceData().query().$promise;
            }
        }
    });
```

So countryData is successfully resolved for home state, while is not for create route.

EDIT.

Here is my factory:

```
angular
    .module('GutenChefApp')
    .factory('countryservice', countryservice);

countryservice.$inject = ['$resource'];

function countryservice($resource) {
    var service = {
        countryServiceData: getCountryService
    };

    return service;

    function getCountryService() {
        return $resource('app/data/countries.json');
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the `countryServiceData` method's source?

Comment: But you know  nothing Snow.

Comment: Anyway, the thing is, it is the same for home state and create state, so as it works perfectly for home state, there should some issue with create route.

Comment: The only issue that may be in route itself is the template. If it fails to load, the route won't be resolved. In other case, please, post all the relevant code. Nice allusive joke on @JonSnow 's profile.

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I got it work, problem was with other non this issue related dependencies.